# Are we supposed to use exception types from the standard library?

Tags: c++, exception, standard-library

The C++ standard library defines some exception types, like `std::exception`, `std::bad_alloc`, and `std::logic_error`. Are we supposed or allowed to use them in our own code at all?

Let's take a concrete example. We define a type `Array`, which holds a fixed number of `int`s and throws a `std::out_of_range` on an "out of range" access. It has a member function `Array::operator[](size_t i)`, which is defined like that:

```
int& Array::operator[](size_t i) {
    if (i >= size)
        throw std::out_of_range({ "out of range" });

    return array[i];
}
```

I think, of course, we can use them (the standard doesn't really prohibit it) but it appears like drawn out of context. IMO, it's similar to a constant

```
const unsigned int percentFactor = 100;
```

which is used for memory allocation:

```
char* ptr = new char[percentFactor];
```

`percentFactor` is **intended** to be multiplied with a `float`/`double` in order to get an integer percentage result. If it's used with for allocating 100 `char`s, it gives the expected results but the two LOCs are completely unrelated otherwise. The same for exceptions. If `std::out_of_range` is only intended for usage within the standard library and I would use it in my own code, the exception mechanism itsself would work but it is unrelated otherwise.

Now, should I use them in my own program/library/API or not?

Comment: I have read the question several times and still do not understand what standard exception classes have to do with a constant integers and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @ChristianHackl `percentFactor` is intended to be multiplied a `float`/`double` in order to get an integer percentage. In my example, it's used for memory allocation, which is **completely** unrelated to percentage calculation. Imagine one wants to allocate 100 `char`s and uses `percentFactor` for it. That gives correct results but is actually unrelated. The same with `std::out_of_range`. If it was only intended to be used for the standard library but then I used for my own programs, it'd work but they are completely unrelated. Admittedly, it might not be the example. :-)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Better example: imagine, if an "out of range" access is performed, a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown. The exception mechanism itsself might work perfectly well, but `std::bad_alloc` actually has nothing to do with an "out of range" access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

`std::out_of_range` is designed for exactly this purpose.

All your exceptions should either be from `<stdexcept>` or derived from the exception classes therein.

Edit:

Expanding a bit... throwing

- a `std::logic_error` (or something derived from it) implies that the *program itself* is incorrect (consumer code is trying to do something outside the design parameters).
- a `std::runtime_error` (or subclass thereof) implies that what was attempted was legal, but not possible at this time (for example because a file was missing, or some other *run-time* issue).

Comment: Is that only with `std::out_of_range` or can I use any of them without further research?

Comment: @cad see above for a simple explanation of which ones to use and when.